# ConstrainedProperties for non domain classes but with @Validateable

Tags: grails, groovy

Greetings.

Browsing in google i've found out you can retrieve a lists of the constrainsts for a domain class in grails.

```
def constraintList= new DefaultGrailsDomainClass(User.class).constrainedProperties
```

Is it possible to do the same thing for classes that are not command objects or domain objects but have the @Validatable annotation?

Comment: Ok. I didn't drescribe enough my question.

Comment: Ok. I didn't drescribe enough my question. I'm playing with vaadin and my idea is to implement somekind of validator factory that works with vaadin forms based on the the constrains of the object. Similar to jquery-validation-ui-plugin (http://code.google.com/p/jquery-validation-ui-plugin/) but with vaadin. In order to achieve this I need to look for the properties of the object to retrieve their constraints defined. This can be done with a domain object or a command object. But a haven't found a way to do this whit a class with the @Validateable.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but for the `@Validateable` annotation to work you need to app the following property to `Config.groovy`

```
// This list should contain the packages that are annotated @Validateable
grails.validateable.packages = ['com.example.package1', 'com.example.package2]
```

Comment: I know that defining in Config.groovy the property grails.validateable.packages alows to use the validation in other classes. The cuestion lies in how to (in execution time) know what constraint's are defined for a class.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't it be enough to peek into the class' `constraints` static property for that?